# Blackberry S-MIME LDAPS

Tags: blackberry, ldap, smime

Blackberry Enterprise Server 10 in place
Windows 2008R2 Active Directory Server LDAPS enabled

I would like to setup the BES10 to retrieve the Public keys from the ADDS through LDAPS for the S-MIME.

With LDAP it works, but when trying to use LDAPS it doesn't work.

Is there somebody knowing if it is supported and if so what I can look at to make it work?

I nowhere find the specifications how to or the requirements.

greets